Detect Collisions Between a Line and a Mesh Swept Along a Line
I have a mesh M, that is made up of triangles. This mesh will then move in a straight line L that you can represent as a single vector. I need to detect if this sweeping mesh will collide with a static line segment, preferably in an a priori (continuous) way. Here is a MRE:
pub struct Triangle {
    pub a: Vec3,
    pub b: Vec3,
    pub c: Vec3,
}

pub struct LineSegment {
    pub a: Vec3,
    pub b: Vec3,
}

pub struct Mesh(Vec<Triangle>);

fn collides(mesh: Mesh, path: Vec3, line: LineSegment) -> bool {
    // ...
}

And to better help visualize it, here is an interactive example:
https://www.desmos.com/3d/awxbt16pqj
I need to detect if the gray line will collide with the moving (red) cube.
All resources online are either mesh/mesh collision detection or use discrete simulation steps. I would like this to be as fast as possible (as it will be run hundreds of thousands of times on the gpu), and I would like to use a continuous solution. It is also important to mention that I do not need to know about where the 2 items will collide, just if they will.

Since the mesh is a cube that moves along a line, just perform a vertex-to-vertex extrusion from start to finish. Then just apply your standard line-triangle collision test for each extruded triangle. And you only need to recompute the answer if the line changes position during the cube’s traversal. BTW, a priori does not mean continuous. It means, essentially, given — something that we accept without need for experiential proof.

I also hated it when my math teacher was sloppy about "lines" and "line-segments". Your question is about line-segments, yes?

@BitTickler Yes, I apologize if my wording was vague, the target object is a line segment, and the path is just a vector that extends from the mesh

@Dúthomhas the approach you suggested will not detect the cases in which the target line segment is fully enclosed though, correct? That is to say, the line can be inside the extruded mesh without intersecting any triangles

Correct, it won’t work for a line segment. Once you have a hit on the line, then you must apply some inside/outside testing.

Can we consider this problem as the Mesh is stopping and the line segment moves in the line L ?
That is, can be considered as Mesh vs plane(has infinite length and limited width) ?

I am not sure, how desirable solutions with a few branches are in the context of GPU architectures. I see 2 cases: A The line segment (P2 - P1) is colinear with the cubes direction. B This is not the case. Case A needs special treatment and case B can be solved with a (closed formula) solving of a system of 3 linear equations and hessian normal form. I was tinkering with that a bit and it looked promising. You should only need addition and multiplication but no trigonometric functions (sin, cos, tan...). You can save processing time if you first do inexact checks.
